# What is the sampling rate in this case?

Tags: discrete-signals, sampling

A signal $x=\sin(\pi t/4)$
sampled at every $t=1$ sec.
so $T=1$ sec
Sampled signal is then $x=\sin(\pi n/4)$, 
What is the sampling rate in this case?, 
And according to Nyquist sampling rate what should be the minimum sampling rate to sample this signal?

Comment: Sampling frequency is obviously 1 Hz. General form of Sinusoidal signal is $\sin(2\pi f_0 t)$ - I don't care about phase. Sampling frequency must be then at least $2f_0$

Answer (score 3):

For the sine wave $\sin ((\pi/4)t)$ , the minimum sampling frequency is greater than 1/4 Hz. That amounts to a sampling period less than 4 seconds. In your case, sampling period of 1 second is therefore a valid choice.

Answer (score 2):

Some things to think about:

- The Nyquist Theorem requires the sampling rate be a minimum of twice the bandwidth of the signal, which, in general, is not twice the fundamental frequency of the carrier.

  - For a lowpass signal, twice the bandwidth equates to twice the highest frequency component.
  - For a bandpass signal, twice the bandwidth is **NOT** twice the highest frequency component.
- The spectrum of a sampled sinusoid approaches $\delta(f-f_0) + \delta(f+f_0)$
- The bandwidth of a $\delta$ $<<$ $2f_0$
- The sampling rate, $F_s$, is the inverse of the sampling period, $T_s$, which is 1 Hz in your case.
- Assuming $x(t) = \sin(\pi/4t) = \sin(w_0t) = \sin(2\pi f_0)$, then $w_0 = \pi/4$ rad/s and $f_0 = 1/8$ Hz
- So, $2f_0$ = 1/4 Hz
- [Take a look at this similar question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/2750/what-is-the-bandwidth-of-a-real-sinusoidal-tone-and-pulse/2751#2751)

Answer (score 2):

The sampling frequency is the inverse of the period T so $F_s = 1/T = 1/1s = 1 Hz$. The Nyquist rate is the double of the maximum frequency of the signal. In your case the signal has only one frequency component $f = 1/8$. So, $F_N = 2 f = 1/4$. Since in your case is a $sin$ signal, the the sampling frequency should be greater (not greater or equal) than the Nyquist rate, in order to avoid aliasing.

Answer (score 0):

Sampling frequency is 1 Hz, since the sampling period T = 1sec. i.e greater than 1/4 Hz. Sorry for the wrong expression.

Comment: The highest signal frequency is 1/8 Hz and thus Fmin = 0.25 Hz.

Comment: yea so the sampling frequency must be greater than 0.25 Hz right?. Sorry guys for the wrong input. Got a little confused myself. *My Apologies*

Comment: Yes, $f_\mathrm{s}>0.25\,\text{Hz}$ must hold. No problem, fortunately anwers can be edited.